# Trim trailing and leading spaces in a file fields separated by delimiter using unix command

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

**Input file:**

```
abc  | hello |123 |

def  | hi ram | 456 |
```

**output file should be as follows**

```
abc|hello|123|

def|hi ram|456
```

Please let me know if we can achieve this using awk or sed commands. I want to execute the same in perl using system command

Comment: You need to show some work, like you've tried to use sed or awk.

Comment: Wait? What? You want to call an external program from Perl in order to do some text manipulation? One of us is missing something fundamental here :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lpe 's/ \s*[|]\s* /|/xg' file
```

output

```
abc|hello|123|
def|hi ram|456|
```

Comment: or: `perl -F'(\|)' -wanE'say map s/^\s*(.*?)\s*\z/$1/r, @F'`

Comment: I got distracted by how one properly specifies `|` as a delimiter with the `-F` switch.  Does it need to be escaped?  I always get a little confused by that and so test instead of recognizing the shortcut :)

Comment: @ysth I see what are you up to, but it doesn't compile. ah, `v5.10` here `:)`

Comment: then: `perl -MString::Util=trim -F'(\|)' -wanE'say map trim($_), @F'`  (capturing the `|` is only necessary because the implicit split doesn't use -1 as third param so you can't keep it from dropping trailing fields).

Comment: @Miller yes, it needs to be escaped (regex).

Comment: Scalar::Util needs to borg String::Util

Comment: @ysth it is strange that trim doesn't take $_ as default parameter.

Comment: When I tested, I was somewhat surprised that `-aF'\|'` actually cut off the trailing `|`.  Is that part of the spec?  `perl -aF'\|' -lne 's/^\s+|\s+$//g for @F; print join "|", @F'`

Comment: @Miller yes, ysth mentioned that eralier (-1 third parameter)

Comment: Ahh, so he did.  Yeah, that's why I used split -1 in my deleted example.  I was just surprised by that functionality.

Comment: The OP's post doesn't include it, but your solution doesn't cover spacing for the beginning and end of line.  `s/\s*([|]|^|$)\s*/$1/g`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
perl -i -lne 'print join "|", map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_} split /\|/, $_, -1' data.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below awk command to remove all the leading and trailing spaces in the columns separated by `|` symbol,

```
$ awk -F'|' '/^ *$/{next;} {gsub (/ *$/,"",$1); gsub (/^ */,"",$2); gsub (/^ */,"",$3); gsub (/ *$/,"",$2); gsub (/^ */,"",$3); gsub (/ *$/,"",$3); print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"}' imp
abc|hello|123|
def|hi ram|456|
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F'|'                  # Field seperator is set to |.

/^ *$/{next;}          # Awk skips from doing the operation on seeing a blank line.

gsub (/ *$/,"",$1);    # Removes the trailing spaces on column no1.

gsub (/^ */,"",$2)     # Removes the leading spaces on column number2.

print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"  # Prints the column1,2,3 delimited by a pipe symbol.
```

Comment: can you please explain the solution, and also please let me know if it works if all the fields have leading & trailing spaces

Comment: Thanks Avinash, Can u also let me know how can we rearrange the columns. For e.g:

hello|123|abc 

hi ram|456|def

Comment: It's rearranged. did you have any doubt in my command? If yes, then which part?

Comment: lets assume i have columns like abc|123|yes and i want to rearrange that to 123|abc|yes using awk how can i achieve it? I have lakhs of rows in a file, so basically i need to change the order of columns

Comment: just chage the column number while printing. Run this command `echo 'abc|123|yes' | awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{print $2,$1,$3}'`

Comment: executed awk -F'|' '/^ *$/{next;} {gsub (/ *$/,"",$1); gsub (/^ */,"",$2); gsub (/^ */,"",$3); gsub (/ *$/,"",$2); gsub (/^ */,"",$3); gsub (/ *$/,"",$3); print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"}' imp in shell it worked, but  perl script using system("awk -F'|' '/^ *$/{next;} {gsub (/ *$/,"",$1); gsub (/^ */,"",$2); gsub (/^ */,"",$3); gsub (/ *$/,"",$2); gsub (/^ */,"",$3); gsub (/ *$/,"",$3); print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"}' imp"); i encounter error like String found where operator expected at /tmp/abc.pl line 247, near "",$1); gsub (/^ */,"",$2); gsub (/^ */,""(Missing operator before ",$2); gsub (/^ */,"?)

Comment: I understood that I have started the double quotes in system command and used again in between the command so it couldn't identify where exactly its ending. so i used single quotes instead of double quotes in gsub, still it doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: post your command in pastebin.com and provide back the link here.